# Django forms: Creating checkbox form from CharField in a model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

My end goal is to render an HTML list of checkboxes for all the possible `Group`s in my database to then use in various AJAX requests. I can do this by (in the template) manually creating a form and rendering it inside `<input type='checkbox'>` with the appropriate labels, then taking care of the form process manually in the views.

I wanted to see if using Django Forms saved me any work. I created a `Form` that looks like this:

```
class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Groups
    fields = ['group_name']
    widgets = {
        'group_name': forms.CheckboxInput,
    }
```

And then created a formset using all the `Groups` objects in my database.

```
GroupFormSet = modelformset_factory(Groups, form=GroupForm)
all_groups_can_edit = GroupFormSet(queryset=Groups.objects.all())
```

When this is rendered in my template, the resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="id_form-0-group_name">Group name:</label><input id="id_form-0-group_name" maxlength="64" name="form-0-group_name" type="checkbox" value="Student">  
</div>
```

The label for my checkbox is always `'Group name:'`, but the value of the class is correct (`'Student'` in this example).

I want my HTML to look like this:

```
<div>
    <label for="id_form-0-group_name">Student:</label><input id="id_form-0-group_name" maxlength="64" name="form-0-group_name" type="checkbox" value="Student">  
</div>
```

How can I change my `GroupForm` class to make the label for my checkbox correspond to the name of the particular object used in the form?